# Custom user_logged_in signal BEFORE django updates last_login

Tags: python, django

I'd like to show a notification to user with some stats (e.g how many items have been sold since last time he logged in)

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def notify_user_on_login(sender, request, user, **kwargs):    
    items = Item.objects.filter(status=Item.HISTORY_STATUS, seller=user, when_trading__gte=user.last_login)
```

However, in this signal `last_login` has already been updated.
According to the source at `django.contib.auth` django also connects signal with function that updates `last_login`:

```
user_logged_in.connect(update_last_login)
```

Is it possible to call my function BEFORE updating? Or get same result without adding custom field or doing some strange magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `last_login` is also updated with a [handler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L17) to that signal, which is surely registered and executed before yours. You might be able to solve your issue by moving your app over `django.contrib.auth` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Signal handlers depending on order doesn't seem like a good idea though. So I would probably replace Django's handler with your own:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import update_last_login

def notify_user_on_login(user):    
    items = Item.objects.filter(status=Item.HISTORY_STATUS, seller=user, when_trading__gte=user.last_login)


@receiver(user_logged_in)
def after_user_logged_in(sender, user, **kwargs):
    notify_user_on_login(user)
    update_last_login(sender, user, **kwargs)

user_logged_in.disconnect(update_last_login)
```

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot that I can simply disconnect that signal.
However, it started working only when I removed `sender` from disconnect args.

Comment: @Azarn oh you're right. It's not filtered by sender. Makes sense being it a specific enough signal